# can't read output as input (linux)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I wrote this code it give me "integer expression expected" error

It can't read the output

```
df -h > dfout.txt    
tail -3 dfout.txt > dfoutput.txt    
cat dfoutput.txt | while read Filesystem Size Used Avail Use Mounted    
do    
use_perc=$5
use_noperc="${use_perc%?}"    
if [ $use_noperc -gt $uservalue ]    
then    
echo "Filesystem $Filesystem is full."    
else    
echo "Filesystem $Filesystem is good."    
fi    
done < dfoutput.txt
```

Thanks in advance for your help!.

Comment: Why do you expect that error?

Comment: The problem is that `$5` contains the fifth argument that the current shell was invoked with (most probably it didn't receive that many arguments, in which case it's undefined). Use the variable you just read the value into.

Comment: Additionally, you should generally double-quote your variable interpolations, although in this script, with the fix, it won't make much difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you haven't defined `$uservalue`

There are also a couple of things you might like to improve on this script:

Try using pipes instead of files.. e.g.:

```
df -ml | tail -n +2 | while read fs size used avail cap iused ifree paused mount
```

Use `tail -n +2` to skip the first line.

You should end up with something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
uservalue=10
df -ml | tail -n +2 | while read fs size used avail cap iused ifree piused mount
do
  use_noperc="${cap%?}"
  if [ $use_noperc -gt $uservalue ]
  then
     echo "$fs Full"
  else
     echo "$fs Not full"
  fi
done
```

Comment: my tasks are:
1)to take information from df and put it in a new file
2) to remove % from used and compare with entered value and give result if full or not

Comment: Converting the pipe to two operations with a temporary file is a trivial modification. If that is your only complaint, you should simply accept this answer.

Comment: The really trivial modification would be to add a `tee` in the pipeline, but requiring a file seems silly here anyway.

Comment: Your requirements are to put it in a file twice?  Overwriting it each time the script is called?  Good luck with that.  Especially if the script is run twice simultaneously.  Also good luck putting the output of scripts in whatever directory it happens to be run from.